# Can Visual Studio be configured to make Header Files public by default?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I often make C++ Google Test projects inside Visual Studio that test another project via Project References.

For the test project to find the tested project's methods, I need to configure something in the "Public Project Content" of the tested project.

[image: Public Project Content]

By default nothing is public. With every new project I need to edit the properties. So I was wondering, is there a way to make "Yes" the default for "All Header Files are Public", for instance ?

Thanks.

Comment: Create your own project template with Project > Export Template.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom Property Sheet that can be added to a project.

1. `View > Property Manager > Add new Property Sheet` (the wrench/spanner with the star).
2. Name it and save it somewhere. (I'd recommend `"Google.Test.Default.props"` the quotes are required)
3. Open the sheet by double-clicking on it in the list.
4. Change *only* the properties relevant to default Google Test settings.
5. Apply/OK

The list is ordered where higher entries supersede lower entries and the top-most "project" properties contains all changes and can be modified on a per-project basis.

Then, for every subsequent project:

1. `View > Property Manager > Add existing property sheet`
2. Navigate to the previously saved `Google.Test.Default.props` file.
3. Reorder in the list as needed.
4. Done.

If you've changed any settings in the top-most project settings you'll have to go through them and change the relevant settings to `<Inherit from parent or project defaults>` to have the project use the new property sheet.